# update data based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table with following fields

```
id           int
name         varchar
dob          date/time
```

Now, I have another table called user_map table, with 2 fields

```
oldid        int
newid        int
```

user_map table is used for storing user id mapping, field 'oldid' is user's old id (which is current user id from user table), and 'newid' is user id going to be assigned

I need a single update query, which can update user id for all users in user table

How should it work? Well, for each id in user table, there will be only 1 record matching in user_map table.

id from user table matches oldid from user_map table, and it should be replaced by newid

For example (ignore dob field please)

user table

```
       id                   name                     dob
        1                    aaa                     0000-00-00 00:00:00
        2                    bbb                     0000-00-00 00:00:00
        3                    ccc                     0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

user_map table

```
      oldid       newid
        1           6   
        2           7   
        3           8
```

After query, user table should look like

user table

```
       id                   name                     dob
        6                    aaa                     0000-00-00 00:00:00
        7                    bbb                     0000-00-00 00:00:00
        8                    ccc                     0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

how can I achieve this? is it possible in 1 query only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following query

```
update `user table` a, `user_map` b  set a.id=b.newid where a.id=b.oldid
```

this query is enough to update main table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
update user, user_map set user.id = user_map.newid where user.id = user_map.oldid;

Comment: I didn't understand your query, can you please explain further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following -

**update user
set
  id = um.newid
from
  user un,
  user_map um
where
  un.id = um.oldid**